# how to avoid a link to be crawled multiple times

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am using following code to crawl news using [newspaper](https://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
def extract_news():

    df_news = pd.read_csv(r"file.csv")

    list=[]
    for ind in df_news.index:
        dict={}
        article = Article(df_news['link'][ind])
        article.download()
        article.parse()
        article.nlp()
        dict['Date']=df_news['date'][ind]
        dict['Source'] = df_news['source'][ind]
        dict['link'] = df_news['link'][ind]
        dict['Title']=article.title
        dict['Article']=article.text
        dict['Summary']=article.summary

        list.append(dict)

        news_df=pd.DataFrame(list)
        time.sleep(5)

        news_df.to_csv("articles.csv", mode = 'a', index = True, encoding='utf-8')
```

But the problem is I get duplicate results. Can someone help me how to avoid them? Thank you

Comment: keep a record of visited links, e.g. a `set`/`list` and check if link was already visited.  And don't use `list` and `dict` as names.

Comment: please edit those names >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked for duplicates in your source?

You can check your `df_news` for duplicates and drop them:

```
...
df_news = pd.read_csv(r"file.csv")
df_news = df_news.drop_duplicates(subset='link', keep="first")

lst=[]
for ind in df_news.index:
...
```